# Laptop Dual Boot - Wifi adapter not recognized / not found

Tags: linux, wifi

i very recently installed Linux on a laptop. My problem is that it doesnt seem to find the wifi adapter at all, there's not even an option to turn it on or off. It still sees the ethernet adapter just fine. Can any of you give me some pointers of what to do or where to look?

Comment: What is the WiFi adapter (specifically) and what distro/version?

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`